# How can I change a Craiglist post's US state?

Tags: craigslist

I wonder how I can change a Craiglist post's US state. E.g., if I first created a post in the region "SF Bay Area", how can I change it to another region such as "Boston"?

When editing the post, I couldn't find the option (changing the address through "edit map" doesn't change the region, even when specifying a different state and zip code):

[image: Unpublished draft with a map of San Jose, CA streets and a street address in MA underneath]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the top five most annoying things about Craigslist.  In my case, it keeps defaulting to Victoria, Canada, I live in the US.  Changing it is not possible.  I have to completey redo it.  And, you can't tell the area until you are on page three!!!

Simply bad programming.  This would be an easy fix.